# How do I not let my explosion go through the walls like bomberman?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, physics, raycasting

I have this problem that I want to fix. Every time I place a bomb it goes pass through the wall even if I added a Layermask to tell if it's a wall or not.

### [image]

```
public LayerMask levelMask;
public GameObject explosion;

void Start()
{
    Invoke("Explode", 1f);
}

void Explode()
{
    Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    StartCoroutine(CreateExplosions(Vector2.up));
    StartCoroutine(CreateExplosions(Vector2.down));
    StartCoroutine(CreateExplosions(Vector2.right));
    StartCoroutine(CreateExplosions(Vector2.left));

    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
    Destroy(gameObject, .3f);
}
```

---

```
private IEnumerator CreateExplosions(Vector3 direction)
{

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) 
    { 

    RaycastHit hit; 

    Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0,.5f,0), direction, out 
    hit, i, levelMask); 

    if (!hit.collider) 
    { 
    Instantiate(explosionPrefab, transform.position + (i * direction),
    explosionPrefab.transform.rotation); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    break; 
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.05f); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a 3D raycast. Do you have 3D colliders on your maze walls, or 2D colliders?

Comment: I just saw this code somewhere on the internet and it worked fine. But, yes I am using a 2D collider but I don't know how to convert it to 2D because it makes some error when I do it.

Comment: The 2D and 3D physics systems in Unity are separate worlds. You can't detect a 2D collider with a 3D raycast. So you'll need to convert this to 2D to work with your game. Show us how you've tried to convert it and exactly what error you get, and we can help you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed my problem.

```
//I changed the vector to vector2
private IEnumerator CreateExplosions(Vector2 direction)
{

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //I made the 'RaycastHit2D hit' to be the return value of 'Physices2D.Raycast'
        //and sending the information to the 'hit'.
        //I also casted it to vector2 because transform.position was 
        //returning a vector3
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast((Vector2)transform.position + new 
        Vector2(0, .5f), direction, i, levelMask); 

        if (!hit.collider)
        {
            //I also casted it to vector2 because transform.position was 
            //returning a vector3
            Instantiate(explosion, (Vector2)transform.position + (i * direction), 
            explosion.transform.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.05f);
    }
}
```